# which driver is the owner of a handle?

Tags: windows, kernel, handle, computer-forensics

is there any way to determine which driver is the owner of the hanlde?
I mean is it stored any where is Windows objects?
I can see handles via volatilty but all kernel handles are assigned to System.exe pid:4, I need to know exactly which driver is using this system handle?

thanks

Comment: Windows does not usually store this information.  There might be driver debugging tools that will do so, I'm not sure.

Comment: so no way even by offsets of the handles? are these addresses in shared kernel heap?

Comment: As far as I know there is only one kernel heap.  If Driver Verifier is running then memory allocations by the driver(s) being monitored may be tagged, but I'm not sure whether this includes memory the kernel (or another driver) allocates on your behalf, e.g., to create an object.  I'm also not sure whether opening a handle to an existing object involves allocating memory or not; I would guess that it does not, unless the kernel handle table happens to be full.  (Note that although I have done some simple driver development, I am not an expert, so I could be mistaken.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to determine which driver is the owner of the
>   handle?

When kernel modules (or thread in kernel space) call Kernel API (NtCreateFile, for example), the handles are allocated from handle table of System process. In this case, the answer is: no.

> I mean is it stored any where is Windows objects?

I guess no

> I need to know exactly which driver is using this system handle?

Depend on analisys you're doing. If you need to associate an object back to the driver that owns it, you can try to analize _POOL_HEADER structure to obtain information about who produced the allocation. BUT if you need to analyze an executive object (_FILE object, for example), the PoolTag field in this header will be equal to ObjectType.Key, so this way is not very useful for your purpose.
In general, if you're looking for which resources a process can access (i.e. memory-mapped files), you can analyze with *memmap* volatility's plugin the process' page tables and so the memory area of the process. I suggest you to use VAD structures' dedicated plugin so that you can gather an high-level information about virtual address space of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:)

Comment: However I need the handles of kernel level modules, not the user level . For example imagine my program has 2 dlls + 1 executive +1 .sys driver. I need to know about handles owned by the driver. can volatility help?

Comment: Yes it does. I suppose you can not get the handles of the driver because they reside in the handle table of the process System. You can, however, get a clear view of what are the resources that it accesses. If you want an OS abstraction level (rather than CPU with _memmap_), you can parse the VAD tree of your driver (-p PID). The VAD tree describes the memory ranges allocated by a process (driver or user-space) as they might be seen by the process (ie. mapped files or loaded DLLs). The vadtree plugin with _--render=dot_ option also colors VAD nodes associating them to resources they rapresent.